# Azure functions using python docker file

Tags: python, docker, azure-functions

I have followed the tutorial for the Azure Functions using python.
everything wen smooth.
for the next step I need to add a C compiled dependency.
I just added the C compiler + the dependency script rows.
I have edited the Docker file and it now looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

FROM julia:1.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc g++ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install numpy 

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
```

When I build this docker file it look good.
but when I run it it just opens up a GCC promp.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found an issue with your multi stage `FROM` statements. Also, you needed to add `apt-get install make`.
The following works:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

# Adding "apt-get install make" here
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make && apt-get install -y gcc g++ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install numpy 

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
```

Comment: hey. I tried using your Dockerfile it builds but when I try to run it this is what I am getting and he is not accessible through localhost:8080:
PS D:\AzureFunctionTest> docker run -p 8080:80 -it 94073419f251

Python 3.7.11 (default, Jun 29 2021, 20:31:06)

[GCC 8.3.0] on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>>

Comment: Have you cross checked the image id? Try deleting previous images and then build again and then use the new image id. Because it is working fine at my end.